# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell on IntellijIDEA 8.0.1 with GWT 2.6.0

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I am very new to GWT nad trying my first sample application on Intellij 8.0.1 and GWT 2.6
When I run the HTML file I get the following exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java" -Xmx256m -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 8.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Simmi\Desktop\GWT\gwt-2.6.0\gwt-dev-windows.jar;C:\Users\Simmi\IdeaProjects\GWT App Again\src;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\alt-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Simmi\IdeaProjects\GWT App Again\out\production\GWT App Again;C:\Users\Simmi\Desktop\GWT\gwt-2.6.0\gwt-user.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 8.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell -style DETAILED -out "C:\Users\Simmi\.IntelliJIdea80\system\gwt\GWT App Again.GWT App Again2c6ee7c2\GWT_App_Again.592ecf2\run\www" -gen "C:\Users\Simmi\.IntelliJIdea80\system\gwt\GWT App Again.GWT App Again2c6ee7c2\GWT_App_Again.592ecf2\run\gen" myapplication.MyApplication/MyApplication.html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:87)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: What's this `gwt-dev-window.jar` in your classpath? Isn't the GWT SDK coming with a `gwt-dev.jar` instead? That might let IntelliJ IDEA think you're using an oldish version, that used `GWTShell` instead of `DevMode`.

Comment: I am using the GWT-2.6 version, it doesnt have the GWTShell

Comment: Tried the same code on Eclipse, it worked fine !!
Still clueless why isnt the code working on Intellij IDEA